# Cannot import module from virtualenv

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I have created a python package, published it to TestPyPl, and successfully installed it in a virtual environment using pip.
I am in Visual Studio and can see my package inside the virtual environment of my project in the Solution Explorer. So why when I use

```
import MyPackage
```

I get an error "no module named MyPackage"?

Note that the package's setup.py contains the line

```
name="MyPackage",
```

and its __init__.py also contains:

```
name = "MyPackage"
```

It must be something trivial but I can't see it!

Answer (score 0):

Ok just in case some other newby has the same issue, I was packaging the project all wrong. I created the **init**.py and README.md and setup.py files in the folder where my .py files are located, NOT in the root folder, where the .sln file is located!
Once I move those files in the correct folder and re-packaged it, it all worked fine.